# How to replace everything after a given substring with a new string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

I have a .txt file and I want to replace everything that comes after the first occurence of a substring with a new string.

For example, if .txt file contains:

*This is Peter and he likes chocolate pies. It's sunny outside.*

I'd like to be able to replace everything after the world "chocolate" with "bars", so the end result would be:

*This is Peter and he likes chocolate bars*

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A `preg_replace` call will work:

```
$subject = "This is Peter and he likes chocolate pies. It's sunny outside.";
$regex = "#(chocolate).+$#";
$out = preg_replace($regex,"$1 bars.",$subject);
```

You can substitute variables for the word in the search pattern and the replacement pattern if you want.

Answer (score 2):

use a mix of strpos and substr to chop the end off.

```
$str = 'This is Peter and he likes chocolate pies. It\'s sunny outside.';
$find = 'pies';
$replace = 'bars';
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $find)) . $replace;
```

Comment: i like your answer. my problem is though, i dont know what comes after the word "chocolate", i only know that i need to replace everything after "chocolate" with another string. that's why i can't look for "pies" in my situation here

Comment: so use the variable $replace

Comment: yes i need to concatenate the string ending with "chocolate" and the $replace string, but i don't know how to get the first string out

Comment: You could use "chocolate" as $find and the `$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $find) - strlen($find)) . $replace;`

Comment: thanks Muc, your tip worked (just had to put "+" instead of "-" though :)

Comment: @DaveChen what do you have against the mighty regex :(